# LinkedList entering strings into nodes and printing list?

Tags: c, string, loops, while-loop, linked-list

I am trying to use this example to implement a linkedlist in my function:
http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-create-linked-list-display-elements/

SCROLL DOWN TO THE COMMENT:

```
   /** HERE. i don't want the "press 0 to exit",
    * i want to take the new message from global var. 
    * then enter into a new node of the linked list.                
    **/
```

My problem is that i implemented my code wrong, but don't know how to fix this.
i presume i need a loop exit strategy but i am struggling on the how?

```
/**whenever i have a new message, 
this global variable copies that message**/

char msg[30]; 

struct node{        
   char num[30]; 
   struct node *ptr;
   };

typedef struct node NODE; //call struct NODE
NODE *head, *first, *temp = 0; //initialize head, temp value to 0 and first

void function(
    //if my message is available, then...
    if(strlen(msg)!=0) {



    while (choice){ //while true

        head  = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));

        //i copy the new string from the global variable declared above into
        //the linked list....or that is what i am attempting to do

        strcpy(head->num,msg);
        printf("%s\n",s);

        if (first != 0){ 
                temp->ptr = head;
                temp = head;
            }

        else{
                first = temp = head;
            }
            i++;


        /** HERE. i don't want the "press 0 to exit",
        * i want to take the new message from global var. 
        * then enter into a new node of the linked list.                
        **/
        choice=0;

    }

    temp->ptr = 0;
    /*  reset temp to the beginning */
    temp = first;

    while (temp != 0){

        printf("%s\n", temp->num);
        count++;
        temp = temp -> ptr;

        }

        printf("No. of nodes in the list = %d\n", count);



    }}
```

Output on string1:

```
 string1
```

Output on new string2:

```
 string2
```

Basically on every new string, keep adding onto the linkedlist and printing the entire list:

```
 string1
 string2
 ...
```

appeciate any help.

Comment: lot of code is missing. please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: my actual code is too long, so i said that msg(glob var.) will copy new strings every time.

Comment: @user3035890 Do not use global variables. Rewrite the code without global variables.

Comment: please provide code with main function

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I have another function which generates strings, i copy those strings into the global variable

Comment: The code at the [link]( http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-create-linked-list-display-elements/) you mention works fine. What exactly is your problem ?

Comment: @user3035890 It is a bad idea to use global variables. Also it is totally unclear what first and temp are used for.

Comment: @MichaelWalz if you look at the comment /** HERE. i don't want the "press 0 to exit",
        * i want to take the new message from global var. 
        * then enter into a new node of the linked list.                
        **/ ---you can see what my problem is

Comment: It's still unclear. Show an example of what should appear on the screen for a given input.

Comment: @MichaelWalz thats described in the 2nd last line of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void function(node*head)
{

  struct node* head = head;

   while(NULL != head) {
       printf(num);
       head = head->ptr; 
   }

}
```

That is something that will print all the content. To put them into this, you'll need something likes this:

```
struct node* head = NULL;

void putMsg()
{
   if (NULL == head)
   {
       head  = (node *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
       temp = head;
   }
   else
   {
      temp2 = (node *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
      temp->ptr = temp2;
      temp = temp->ptr;
   }
   char message[30];
   scanf("%s", message);
   strcpy(head->num, message);
}
```

Please declare all the variables. The solution is not precise but will navigate you at least.

Comment: 1--> There is no `node *`, its either `NODE *` or `struct node *`. 2--> do not cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: In Microsoft Visual Studio it is necessary casting, because it returns void*. Elsewhere, sorry for the errors. I am doing a plugin now.